# How to fix the tempname() function on Windows 10?

Tags: vimscript, gvim, microsoft-windows

## The problem:

I am getting nothing in return for the `tempname()` function in Vim. More specifically, I kept getting only ".do" assigned to the variable `temp` using the following statement.

```
 let temp = tempname() . ".do"
```

- The complete function that fails to get itself a "temp name":

  ```
  let selectedLines = getbufline('%', line("'<"), line("'>"))
  if col("'>") < strlen(getline(line("'>")))
      let selectedLines[-1] = strpart(selectedLines[-1], 0, col("'>"))
  endif
  if col("'<") != 1
      let selectedLines[0] = strpart(selectedLines[0], col("'<")-1)
  endif
  let temp = tempname() . ".do"
  call writefile(selectedLines, temp)
  " *** CHANGE PATH AND NAME TO REFLECT YOUR SETUP. USE \\ INSTEAD OF \ ***
  exec "!start C:\\Vim\\vimfiles\\ftplugin\\Stata-Vim-Suite\\rundo.exe " . temp
  " Delete the temp file after Vim closes
  au VimLeave * exe "!del -y" temp
  ```

  (The above codeblock is supposed to be the body of function define with`fun! RunDoLines()` on line-1, and `endfun` on the last line.

### Remark

This functions has been running very well for years, and it was only today that it should have failed on both of my Windows machines. (I use this function to send commands from Vim to the terminal of a statistical software.)

## Things that I tried, but did not work

- I followed the instruction on the [this page (vim.wikia)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_errors_that_relate_to_reading_or_creating_files_in_the_temp_or_tmp_environment_on_an_MS_Windows_PC), but `tempname()` still gets me an empty string.

### Related problems

- Additionally, here goes the error message I get when trying to run `PlugInstall` through [Vim-Plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug). I think this should also be related with my setting for the TEMP files.

[image]

### Minimal replication case:

Issuing the following set of commands does not get me any output.

```
:let temp_file = tempname()
:echo temp_file
```

Here goes a screenrecord demonstrating the problem:

[image]

Comment: What if you set `$TMP`? `let $TMP = $HOME` or some other convenient path?

Answer (score 2):

### Simple and short solution

In `.vimrc`, drop the following line; and create `temp_dir` in the home directory.

```
let $TMP=$HOME . "/temp_dir"
```